# Need Help to implement Tincan Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, tin-can-api

I'm working on tincan JavaScript API. The issue my data format is total change and TinCan have specified a why to pass data along with call. Help me to adjust my data in TinCan Api format. Here is sample data one of my call.

var data = {
"groupId": "groupId",
"groupName": "gNameEncrypt",
"tutorNames": "tutorNames",
"actorNames": "actorNames",
"otherNames": "otherNames"
};

Current what i do i simply decode this data and send it like this.

```
var actionList = new TinCan(
    {
    recordStores: [{
                       endpoint: "http://example.com",
                       username: username,
                       password: password,
                       allowFail: false
                  }]
});

                var action = new TinCan.Agent({
                    "name": "insert"
                });

                actionList.getStatements({
                    'params': {
                        'agent': action,
                        'verb': {
                            'id': $.base64.encode(data)
                        }
                    },
                    'callback': function (err, data) {
                        console.info(data.more);
                        var urlref = "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ":" . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $uriParts[0] . "?" ?>t=" + data.more.TutorToken;
                        window.location.href = urlref;
                    }
                });
                crypt.finish();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really two parts here:

1. need to get data into an xAPI (formerly Tin Can) format, and
2. the code itself.

In depth,

1. I think you need to take another look at how xAPI is used in general. Data is stored a JSON "Statement" object that has 3 required properties and various other optional ones. These properties often contain complex objects that are very extensible. It is hard to tell from what you've shown what you are really trying to capture and what the best approach would be. I suggest reading some material about the xAPI statement format. http://experienceapi.com/statements-101/ is a good starting point, and to get at least some coverage of all the possibilities continue with http://experienceapi.com/statements/ .
2. The code you've listed is attempting to get already stored statements based on two parameters rather than trying to store a statement. The two parameters being "agent" and "verb". In this case We can't tell what the verb is supposed to be since we don't know what `data` contains, I suspect this isn't going to make sense as a verb which is intended to be the action of a statement. Having said that the fact that the "actor" has a value of `action` is questionable, as that really sounds more like what a "verb" should contain. Getting the statements right as part of #1 should make obvious how you would retrieve those statements. As far as storing those statements, if you're using the `TinCan` interface object you would need to use the `sendStatement` method of that object. But this interface is no longer recommended, the recommended practice is to construct a `TinCan.LRS` object and interact directly with it, in which case you'd be using the `saveStatement` method.

   I would recommend looking at the "Basic Usage" section of the project home page here: http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanJS/ for more specifics look at the API doc: http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanJS/doc/api/latest/

Comment: #Brian J. Miller i understand what you said? I also follow these link to implement TinCan. But my main concern is my data in my case my data is changed with each statement. Here is test link of my App http://test.lip-app.eu please look into this and suggest me how would i adjust data in tincan object?